# gnuplot - plot difference between two columns with pseudocolumn 0

Tags: windows, gnuplot

I have a .csv file organized as follows:

```
425;490
160;343
390;487
35;231
...
```

I want to plot the difference of (row1-row2) on the y-axis, and the pseudocolum 0 as the x-axis.

So far, i've tried

```
plot "test.txt" using $0:($1-$2)
```

which throws

```
column() called from invalid context
```

On the other hand

```
plot "test.txt" (using $0:($1-$2))
```

seems to work but throws

```
'plot "test.txt" (using $0:($1-$2))'
```

in the console.

So my question:
What would be the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
plot 'text.txt' using 0:($1-$2)
```

or

```
plot 'text.txt' using ($1-$2)
```

Comment: You first need to tell gnuplot that your columns are separated by semicolons: `set datafile separator ";"`